# When does the "rollback" link appear?

Tags: support, review

I was checking the review page here on meta, and I have noticed that one of my questions included, between the usual links I could use (e.g. *edit*, *close*, and *delete*), a *rollback* link I have never seen before in any Stack Exchange site.

[image: screenshot]

While I understand what its purpose could be, I have the following questions:

- Was the link recently introduced?
- When does the link appear? Does it require a minimum reputation?
- Should the link appear in all the Stack Exchange sites, or is it only visible on this very site, for now?
- Is the link only limited to the review page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit history of a post, there has *always* been a `rollback` link. So this functionality already existed in the system from back in the early days.

As for the `/review` path that is simply *a bit of everything*, it checks whether to put the rollback link as opposed to posts shown on the normal site. So, if one of your posts is marked as low quality and someone has edited that it gives you the option to roll it back.

Recent changes [can be seen here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), but I don't feel like that this is a recent change but has been here since that the `/review` path has been here.

The link should appear on every site, and as mentioned has always been available in the edit history.

*Eventually, you'll need a developer to confirm when this was implemented...*

Comment: I've never seen this link on Stack Overflow when reviewing posts (which have been edited). P.S. If you ask people, they'll tell you I'm a [cyborg](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=879176#879176) who has reviewed over 30,000 posts.

Comment: @animuson However, your Q&A count is low as a result. Thus you never get to see a post of your own...

Comment: I wasn't aware your own questions appeared. I thought it was forbidden to review your own posts... Didn't notice that part of the question.

Comment: @animuson: Hmm, I think your own posts are forbidden. But I guess that `/review` does allow you to handle an edit by someone else on your own post, but never shows a revision you made yourself...

Comment: @animuson I have reviewed my own posts several times on Gaming.  It's rare, but not impossible.  I distinctly remember because I brought it up in chat how weird it was.  What was I supposed to do, upvote it?