# No rollback link

Tags: support, rollbacks

I stumbled upon an edit which IMHO deleted a little bit too much: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12740575/2 and wanted to rollback that edit and provide an edit of my own. I want to restore the text "in order to work with multiple classes (ie. fadetwo, fadethree, etc)." because it seems to be relevant for the question.

But I don't see a rollback link. Does that mean that I have too little reputation? Or is this option removed to prevent rollback wars?

Note: [When does the "rollback" link appear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124573/139600) does not answer my question! It's about when one sees the rollback link when reviewing, but I am **not** reviewing this question.

Comment: I see the rollback link on that question, at least if I click on "Return to Revisions" first... Shall I roll it back for you, so you can put in the new changes?

Comment: Thank you, this would be nice. Anybody knows why I don't see the rollback link?

Comment: OK, it's rolled back. But the ability to roll back comes with editing privileges, yes, at 2000 rep. I'll put that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you again! I just made the edits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, if you don't have full editing privileges (at 2000 rep for graduated sites, 1000 for sites in public beta), you don't get the "rollback" links in the revision history, unless the post is marked community wiki (editing CW posts requires 100 reputation points), or it's your own post.